# How to find a specific function with a set of solutions

Tags: functions, circles

I am trying to find a specific function that takes in 2 numbers(coordinate points on a circle) and outputs some number result. I've attached an image for visual reference. But at the coordinate (1,0) the result has to be -1, at the coordinate (0.7,0.7) the result has to be 0.75, and at the coordinate (0,1) the result has to be 1.

What would be the best way to go about finding the equation for something like this?

[visual image of wanted results for each coordinate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fz2P.png)

Comment: $0.75\times2^{1119}x^{1000}y^{1234} - x + y$

Comment: There is not a "specific" function for this. There exist uncountably many functions having those three values. InfiniteLooper has playfully given one answer (note that you will need the actual point on the circle, not $(0.7, 0.7)$, which is a little off the circle, for the middle value to be correct). If also $x, y \ge 0$ as shown in your picture, you can consider the function to be of $x$ only, since for each such $x$ there is only one $y$ with $(x,y)$ on the circle. For example: $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1& x< 0.5\\0.75&0.5\le x\le 0.8\\-1&0.8<x\end{cases}$$